# past simple vs. past continuous in a time clause

Tags: grammar, tenses

How can we explain the difference between these two sentences?

> I saw his concert when he performed here.
>
> I saw his concert when he was performing here.

I know that the first sentence refers to a completed action and the second sentence to a continuous action. But if someone asks me when either of the tenses are used, I won`t be able to give any answer. How will I explain to the listener on what to choose and when?

Answer (score 1):

In the specific case of your example, the strict meanings are as follows:

> I saw his concert when he performed here

means *he performed in one concert here, which I attended*

> I saw his concert when he was performing here

means *he performed in a number of concerts here, and I attended one of them*.

But neither sentence is used strictly according to those precise meanings in normal conversational English; both forms are commonly used to convey either strict meaning. If you wanted to make your meaning totally unambiguous, you would have to use one or other of the forms described above.

Comment: Can simple past here refer to a habitual activity too? i.e by saying 'he performed here' we mean 'when he used to perform'

Comment: @Azad: I don't think so, at least not without a qualifier. *I saw him a number of times when he performed here* logically means that it was an ongoing activity; but *he performed here* by itself could mean one or many performances - it needs qualification.